# Volume group "vgubuntu" not found

Tags: boot, 20.04, log

Ubuntu Desktop 20.04.1 LTS

Is the following at the top of the boot log a problem that I should fix? The login screen appears and I can log in.

```
Volume group "vgubuntu" not found
Cannot process volume group vgubuntu
```

Comment: Have you recently deleted some partitions or removed a hard drive?

Comment: I recently tried to add a hard drive and then removed it. See this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305989/applications-fail-to-launch-in-ubuntu-20-04-desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to my other issue and so I assume this is not an issue at all.