# Fixing GPU hang caused by i915 driver

Tags: intel-graphics, gpu, debugging, gpu-driver, i915

Ran updates on my laptop recently, and after rebooting, my laptop started behaving weirdly. After I logged in, the screen started flickering, and as soon as I opened a window (the application menu worked just fine), the whole screen froze, except that I was still able to move the mouse.

dmesg is reporting a GPU hang, dmesg output cna be found here: https://pastebin.com/jha5bXQe . The problem still persists after a complete system reinstall, and after installing all updates.

What could I try to get the PC back to working?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04.1 LTS. As I said, a recent update broke it, and a reinstall didn't help. Additionally, Manjaro Gnome also behaved weirdly, but Manjaro XFCE worked just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

z.Z. kannst du die "nomodeset" option beim booten nutzen.

- im Grub Menü Taste "e" drücken
- nomodeset an der richtigen Stelle einfügen (s.h. ubuntuusers nomodeset)
- "F10" drücken
- bei jedem bootvorgang

oder dauerhaft in /boot/grub/grub.cfg eintragen

bis die Inteltreiber aktualisiert wurden.

---

currently you can use the "nomodeset" option when booting.

- Press the "e" key in the Grub menu
- Insert nomodeset in the right place (see ubuntuusers nomodeset)
- Press "F10"
- with every boot process

or enter it permanently in /boot/grub/grub.cfg

until the Intel drivers have been updated.

Comment: I don't check my inbox very often, so I'm seeing your reply a bit late. I already went full computer nerd on that problem and let apt print all updatable packages to a file after a system reinstall with `apt list --upgradable`. Then, I made a regex to strip away everything except the package names (`perl -pe 's/\/.*\[[^\]]+]//g' updates.txt > updates2.txt`). Btw when working with regex I highly recommend https://regexr.com , really handy. Then I wrote a bash script that read the current "index" from another file, and I simply install ten packages at a time, then make a snapshot with timeshift.

Comment: Then, if the problem appears, I simply roll back to previous versions until I have found the 'defective' package. So yeah, i found a dirty workaround. But since your answer seems helpful, I accepted it and upvoted it because I know how hard it is to get reputation in the beginning.

Comment: @VincentGuttmann would you please post the name of the offending package here? I have the same issue. I'm using "nomodeset" as a workaround but I stuck with limited screen resolution. Many thanks Nick

Comment: It lead nowhere. It suddenly appeared after a few reboots, but the package was nowhere to be found. I just gave up on this as all I do on that laptop is office work and nomodest is plenty fine for me. But if you want, I can upload the script to my github or github gists so you can do it yourself. A replacement of the offending laptop is long overdue anyways (imagine a 5yo laptop with a low-end Intel processor, 3rd gen 2 core), and the final nail in the coffin is that this specifllic processor doesn't support AVX, which is required for TensorFlow.

Comment: @matthew But there were some graphics driver updates recently. I haven't tested yet, but maybe they fixed that bug. I mean, they introduced it I think in December, if not later, and I'd assume that'd be the normal turnaround time for noncritical Bugfixes.

Comment: Also, one more thing I will try is to switch from X11 over to wayland, just to see if it is the (mostly unmaintained) X Server causing the problems, or indeed a driver bug (which would seem weird, this chip is quite old and a driver update at this point in the product life cycle doesn't make any sense).

Comment: @VincentGuttmann thanks for the additional info. So far none of the updates I've installed have fixed the driver bug. I don't fully follow your comment about using `apt list --upgradable`, and as you mention that this hasn't solved the problem for you I don't see much value in sharing your script, but thanks for offering :)

Comment: @VincentGuttmann yep sounds like you need a new laptop! My ubuntu box is primarily a media and file server. The processor is also not powerful as I pulled it from an old Eth mining rig. Are you working on an interesting project with TensorFlow?

Comment: I was going to dive into machine learning, but that project is also on hold because my processor doesn't support AVX (Advanced Vector eXtensions), an extension to the x86 instruction set which is required by tensorflow. It was introduced in 2007, but apparently, it wasn't needed for my laptop or something like that

Answer (score 1):

After 20.04 apt update & upgrade at 12/1/2021 X-windows freeze just after login, only cursor move, but ctrl-alt-F3 gave consol and dmesg gave: i915 GPU HANG

1. bios update (Asrock B85) didn't help
2. grub update: nomodeset didn't help

But stable lowlantency kernel seems work fine.

I have had Ubuntu and dual monitor setup all time latest 14 years in my desktop. Lately there has been several unsolved problem with the Xserver config (20.10 can't install into dual setup at all, resolution problems with vga, reso conflicts, etc (yes, it was hard to configure X by hands, but it was possible;-)).

Comment: I don't feel like configuring X11 myself, though I will try switching to Wayland.

Answer (score 0):

appending `i915.enable_psr=0` to `/etc/default/grub` GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and `sudo update-grub2` then reboot solved it

Answer (score 0):

If someone still has this problem.

```
i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GPU HANG: ecode 9:1:85dffffb, in gnome-shell [2712]
```

My solution was to update kernel from 6.1 to 6.5 using backports. `sudo apt install -t backports linux-image-amd64` (change according to architecture).